# 18.04: How to set up Nessus VM

Tags: virtual-machine, security, troubleshooting

I'm trying to set up a [Nessus 8 VM][1], connected through NAT.

I enter the user and password and it replies:

"Failed to connect to https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-lts. Check your Internet connection or proxy settings"

but I can perfectly access to internet

The VM provides both user/password to the VM and Nessus

one the things thats is said to do is edit the configuration file in the following fields that are in the path /etc/netplan/ and in this folder there is a file 50-cloud-init.yaml

ens33: 1.1.2.16/24 fixed IP,VMnet2, bridge network card

ens34: DHCP gets ip, VMnet3, bridge networkcard

one advice that is made is to modify the NIC configuration according to the environment

I think (correct me if Im wrong) is that the problem may be the configuration file

what do I put on the ens33 and ens34 because Im blocked here and I can't proceed however I have access to the command line

How can I finalize the setup of the VM?

Im trying to run the VM on Windows 10 home on VMware 15.5

The VM is UBUNTU version 18.04.2 lts (bionic beaver)

kernel Linux 4.15.0-46-generic

architecture x86-64

I can run commands like if config I can't do apt-get commands

I have setupt my VMnet2 as host only with ip 192.168.1.0 and subnet 255.255.255.0 this on VMWare Virtual Network editor

On the the Nessus VM I have tried

Network adapter Custom (VMnet2)

Network adpter 2 I already have tried NAT, Bridged, Briged (replicate physical network connection statate)

After make the login on the VM I already have tried 192.168.1.0/24, the ip given when doing ifconfig, that same ip/24

I already have tried all the possible combinations that I remeber but it keeps saying

"Failed to connect to https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-lts. Check your Internet connection or proxy settings"

Honestly I don't know What I can be doing wrong

Comment: I already have added some more information hoping you can help me in this issue